# Quando usar void* e auto*?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, conversão-de-tipo, c++11

O C++11 nos disponibilizou o tipo `auto` (*automatic*). Ele pode transferir de tipo pela primeira vez. Mas antes dele, as pessoas costumavam a usar o `void*`, em que você fazia referência no ponteiro. Até hoje uso `void*` (Win32), mas também uso o `auto` e poderia usar o `auto*`. Quais são os benefícios de usar o `auto*`? Devemos substituí-lo pelo `void*`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Os dois tem usos bem diferentes.

O `void*` serve primariamente para poder se passar um ponteiro, para qualquer tipo, em uma função, ou para guardar um ponteiro para qualquer coisa. Uma vez atribuído um valor, este pode ser substituído por outro de qualquer tipo. Possui um grave problema: você perde a informação sobre o tipo original. Na hora de se ler o que tem em um `void*` é necessário fazer um *cast*, e se você não o fizer corretamente o programa vai dar crash. Em C ele é essencial, mas em C++ existem diversas alternativas mais seguras, como hierarquias de classes ou templates. É muito interessante também o [boost::any.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html), que vai acabar entrando para o standard algum dia. E também está ganhando força ultimamente o conceito de *type erasure*, onde você pode criar um tipo que aceite atribuição de objetos de qualquer outro tipo, sem relação explícita, desde que respondam a um conjunto delimitado de comandos, como o operador ++ ou uma função específica. Tem uma explicação muito boa [aqui](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/) sobre isso.

Já o `auto`, a partir do C++11 serve para declarar variáveis cujo tipo vai ser inferido pelo compilador a partir da inicialização delas. Não pode ser utilizada para parâmetro ou como membro de uma classe. Uma vez atribuído um valor para uma variável `auto`, é impossível mudar o tipo da variável, afinal `auto` serve apenas para dizer para o compilador: "não quero escrever o tipo da variável, mas quero que ela seja do tipo daquilo que estou atribuindo". Existe uma certa polêmica quando ao seu uso pois pode levar a criação de código ofuscado. Um uso interessante dele, entretanto, é para minimizar a verbosidade do código, principalmente no uso de iteradores e afins, por exemplo:

```
for (std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator iter = map.begin(); iter != map.end(); ++iter) { ... }
```

versus

```
for (auto iter = map.begin(); iter != map.end(); ++iter) { ... }
```

A segunda opção agride menos a vista, mas para ter certeza absoluta do tipo de `iter` você tem que saber o tipo de `map` e o retorno da função `begin()`.

Resumindo, `void*` é uma solução legada para programação genérica. O `auto` é um simplificador de código, que não substitui o `void*`, embora existam outras alternativas modernas para ele, como eu mencionei acima.

Comment: Seria isso equivalente ao `var` do `C#` ?

Comment: Pois é, pelo que entendi parece ter a mesma funcionalidade do var no C#.

Comment: Não sei dizer pois conheço muito superficialmente C#, mas se o `var` for para declarar variáveis onde o tipo delas é inferido pelo compilador a partir da expressão usada na inicialização delas, deve ser equivalente sim.